# python script to edit a file in vim

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I want to make a python script that:
opens a file, executes the command `i`,
then writes 2 lines of code, hits `escape`
executes the command `ZZ`.
I was thinking along the lines of `os.system("vi program") then os.system("i")` and os.system("code"), but that didn't work because you can only **execute** commands. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## THE CODE

```
import pyautogui
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

vi_proc = Process(target = lambda: os.system("vi program"))
vi_proc.start()

pyautogui.typewrite("i")
pyautogui.typewrite("This code\n")
pyautogui.typewrite("really sucks!")
pyautogui.press("esc")
pyautogui.typewrite("ZZ")

vi_proc.join()
```

## THE BLABLABLA

Well, I really not understand **WHY**, but I coded a working solution. I used [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI), a really simple library that allow you to emulate key and mouse presses and movements.

You may also need to install some sysyem package, like `libjpeg8-dev`. Furthermore, probably you have also to issue the command `xhost +` temporarily before installation.

That said, in `bash` it will be simply:

```
echo -e "This code\nreally sucks!" > program
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear why you want to do this. To truly run an interactive program, you'll have to create a pseudo-tty and manage it from your python script - not for the faint of heart.

If you just want to insert text into an existing file, you can do that directly from python, using the file commands. Or you could invoke a program like `sed`, the "stream editor", that is intended to do file editing in a scripted fashion. The `sed` command supports a lot of the `ex` command set (which is the same base command set that `vi` uses) so i, c, s, g, a, all work.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to run VIM from the command-line, you can use the VIM -c option.  Something like this:

```
gvim -c "normal oFirst line" -c "normal oSecond line" -c "ZZ" foo.txt
```

(Adjust using o, O, i or I as according to where you want the line inserted).

There must be an easier way to insert two lines in a file, though.